# Comparing int and long using IComparable interface

Tags: c#, icomparable

I would like to have expression classes that compare two objects and pass the below test.

```
public abstract class ComparisonExpression
{
    public bool Evaluate(IComparable left, object right)
    {
        if (left == null && right == null)
            return true;

        if (left == null || right == null)
            return false;

        return GetResult(left.CompareTo(right));
    }

    protected abstract bool GetResult(int comparisonResult);
}

public class AreEqualExpression : ComparisonExpression
{
    protected override bool GetResult(int comparisonResult)
    {
        return comparisonResult == 0;
    }
}

// TEST

const int i = 123;
const long l = 123L;
const string s = "123";

Assert.IsTrue(new AreEqualExpression().Evaluate(i, l));
Assert.IsFalse(new AreEqualExpression().Evaluate(i, s));
Assert.IsFalse(new AreEqualExpression().Evaluate(l, s));
```

It seems like IComparable implementation expects the given type matches the current type. I am having an exception like "Object must be of type Int32.".

I thought returning false if types are not equal. It prevents the exception but it brakes the behavior that i want.

Also I thought about a type conversion but this time string and int comparison will return true, which i do not want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to check if I understood correctly: You want the comparer to compare as usual except if both types are "numeric". In that case, you want the comparer to check if the numbers have the same value. If that is what you where asking for: Does this only hold for integer types (byte, short, ...) or also for decimals and floating point numbers?

Comment: No, this should handle any type that implements IComparable. My solution is before comparing I check if both values are numeric. If so, then I convert both values to decimal and then compare. But it is still buggy for double and floats.

Comment: That's what I understand. So, roughly speaking, your algorithm should do the following? a) If both are floating point numbers (float, double) -> compare using floating point values b) If both are integer values (short, int, long, ...) -> compare integer values c) Else, compare as usual. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you define this helper class

```
public static class NumericalHelper {
    public static double AsDouble(this object value, out bool success) {
        if (value is sbyte || value is byte || value is short || value is ushort || value is int || value is uint || value is long || value is decimal || value is ulong || value is float || value is double || value.GetType().IsEnum) {
            success = true;
            return Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
        success = false;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

you can do the comparison like this:

```
public bool Evaluate(IComparable left, object right) {
    if (left == null && right == null)
        return true;

    if (left == null || right == null)
        return false;

    bool isNumerical;
    double leftValue = left.AsDouble(out isNumerical);
    double rightValue = isNumerical ? right.AsDouble(out isNumerical) : 0;

    if (isNumerical)
        return GetResult(Comparer<Double>.Default.Compare(leftValue, rightValue));
    else {
        if (left.GetType() == right.GetType())
            return GetResult(left.CompareTo(right));
        else
            return false;
}
```

**But beware** that equality is usully compared with the `Equals` method or with the `IEquatable` interface, which isn't considered at all in your example. [Here is more information about implementing equality](http://www.aaronstannard.com/overriding-equality-in-dotnet/). This seems to be an issue to me this doesn't fit well in use current class design.